# SFTP : BeanPostProcessor interfere with @ServiceActivator and @MessagingGateway

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

It seems BeanPostProcessor interface implementation is having impact on @ServiceActivator. What should be the way to use BeanPostProcessor with @ServiceActivator. Thanks.

Complete logs are available here [logs](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByEWhJ9QdUASNGJmNTVaZjlGd1k)

Following is Java Config used for SFTP -

```
package com.ftp.example;

import java.io.File;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.expression.common.LiteralExpression;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Gateway;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.IntegrationComponentScan;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessagingGateway;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.integration.file.FileNameGenerator;
import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.outbound.SftpMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.LsEntry;

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableAsync
@IntegrationComponentScan
@EnableIntegration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@PropertySource("file:C:\\DEV\\workspace_oxygen\\ftp-example\\ftp-example.properties")
public class DependencySpringConfiguration {

    private Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DependencySpringConfiguration.class);

    @Value("${project.name}")
    private String applicationName;


    @Value("${${project.name}.ftp.server}")
    private String server;

    @Value("${${project.name}.ftp.port}")
    int port;

    @Value("${${project.name}.ftp.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${${project.name}.ftp.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${${project.name}.ftp.remote.directory}")
    private String remoteDirectory;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public ProcessStarter processStarter() {
        return new ProcessStarter();
    }

/*  @Bean
    public LogInjector logInjector() {
        return new LogInjector();
    }*/


    @Bean
    public FTPOutService fTPOutService() {
        return new FTPOutService();
    }


    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost(server);
        sf.setPort(port);
        sf.setUser(username);
        sf.setPassword(password);
        sf.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(sf);
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toSftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpSessionFactory());
        handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(remoteDirectory));
        handler.setFileNameGenerator(new FileNameGenerator() {

            @Override
            public String generateFileName(Message<?> message) {
                return "fileNameToBeFtp.txt";
            }

        });
        return handler;
    }

    @MessagingGateway
    public interface MyGateway {
        @Gateway(requestChannel = "toSftpChannel")
        void sendToSftp(File file);
    }


}
```

And We are calling gateway object like this while doing SFTP

Main class

```
public class FtpExample {

    public static String[] ARGS;
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FtpExample.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ARGS = args;
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DependencySpringConfiguration.class);

        ProcessStarter processStarter = ctx.getBean(ProcessStarter.class);
        processStarter.startService();
    }
}
```

Other classes -

```
public class ProcessStarter {
    @Inject
    private FTPOutService ftpOutService;

    public void startService() {
        ftpOutService.ftpToBbg();
    }
}



public class FTPOutService {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FTPOutService.class);

    @Inject
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    public void ftpToBbg() {

        log.info("Starting FTP out process...");
        File file = null;
        try {
            file = new File("C:\\Temp\\log\\debug\\ftp\\priceindex\\for-upload\\ftp-example.txt.REQ");
            MyGateway gateway = appContext.getBean(MyGateway.class);
            gateway.sendToSftp(file);
            log.info("File {} written successfully on remote server", file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error while uploading file {}", file, e);
        }
    }

}
```

Above code is working fine unless I am not adding following bean declaration in above defined Java Config -

```
public LogInjector logInjector() {
            return new LogInjector();
}
```

Above bean definition is having following implementation -

```
public class LogInjector implements BeanPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(bean.getClass(), new FieldCallback() {
            @Override
            public void doWith(Field field) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
                // make the field accessible if defined private
                ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
                if (field.getAnnotation(Log.class) != null) {
                    if (org.slf4j.Logger.class == field.getType()) {
                        org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(bean.getClass());
                        field.set(bean, log);
                    }  else if (java.util.logging.Logger.class == field.getType()) {
                        java.util.logging.Logger log = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(bean.getClass().toString());
                        field.set(bean, log);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return bean;
    }
}


@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Documented
public @interface Log {
}
```

Once any BeanPostProcessor implementation is added in Java Config, it creates problem and application not able to see toSftpChannel -

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'toSftpChannel' available  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:685)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:45)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.getRequestChannel(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:327)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.send(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:368)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:477)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:429)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:420)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayCompletableFutureProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayCompletableFutureProxyFactoryBean.java:65)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.sendToSftp(Unknown Source)

Comment: You need to show the complete stack trace - `MessagingGatewaySupport.send` it appears you are sending messages before the application context is initialized.

Comment: Logs are having lots of lines in debug mode. Uploaded on google drive -https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByEWhJ9QdUASNGJmNTVaZjlGd1k

Comment: >`15:01:48.848 [main] INFO com.ftp.example.FTPOutService - Starting FTP out process...` you are starting this process too soon - the application context is not built yet. You need to show that class. You must not start any messaging until the application context is completely built.

Comment: I have added FTPOutService  class in Code. Thanks

Comment: Where do you call that `ftpToBbg()` from ?

Comment: Added FtpExample having main method. Thanks

Comment: What version of Spring Integration do you use? How does it work if you declare `toSftpChannel` `MessageChannel` bean explicitly?

Comment: See my answer, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks what you have:

```
@Bean
public LogInjector logInjector() {
    return new LogInjector();
}
```

If you declare `BeanPostProcessor`s as `@Bean` you have to specify them with the `static` modifier: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factorybeans-annotations

> You may declare `@Bean` methods as static, allowing for them to be called without creating their containing configuration class as an instance. This makes particular sense when defining post-processor beans, e.g. of type `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` or `BeanPostProcessor`, since such beans will get initialized early in the container lifecycle and should avoid triggering other parts of the configuration at that point.